# pygame counting

Tags: python, pygame

in this code I have a list made up of "foods" when my character collides with one of these items, it deletes itself, adds score, and creates a new food in the list. so essentially a new food pops up on the screen. I have enemies that fly around the screen and subtract score, they are also in a list. I'm trying to code my program so when I delete two of the foods a new enemy will be added to the list using "count". But for some reason, it does nothing. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
    def update(self) :
           self.score = self.player.update(self.score)
           for triangle in self.triangles:
               triangle.update(self.screen.get_rect())    
            #self.ball.update(self.screen.get_rect())
                if self.player.rect.colliderect(triangle.rect):
                    self.score -= 2
            for i, food in enumerate(self.foods):
                count = 0
                if self.player.rect.colliderect(food.rect):
                    self.score += 100
                    count += 1
                    del self.foods[i]
                    self.foods.append(Food(random.randint(0, 640), random.randint(0, 448)))
                    if count%2 == 0:
                        self.triangles.append(Ball(random.randint(0, 640), random.randint(0, 448)))
            if self.score < -1:
                pygame.mixer.music.stop()
```

Answer (score 2):

You set the count to 0 at the start of each iteration so it will never increase beyond 1. You need the count to be created outside of the loop.

```
count = 0
for i, food in enumerate(self.foods):
    ...
```

Comment: it still doesn't do anything, even when I put it outside of the loop :/

Comment: Then there is something wrong with the rest of your code. Try putting a print statement where the self.triangles.append call is currently and see if it is called.

Comment: the append is called. A new food does appear on the screen. maybe I'll just do without the count.

Comment: If the append is called then what is the problem? What do you expect to happen and what actually occurs?

Comment: I expected a new enemy to append to its list after I delete 2 foods from the food list. I just tested it again and for some reason I have to delete way more food items though

Comment: I see. The problem is to do with how a game loop works. The update method gets called every frame so unless you are touching two pieces of food at pretty much the same time then this wont be triggered. You need a count value outside your update function that is added to whenever you 'delete a food item'. You could get rid of the count in the update function and create a global variable called count outside of the update function. Or you could count the number eaten in a similar way to how you keep track of the score. Then you increment that each time through.